# avoid cursors while updating

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
+--------+-----------+-------+
| PartId | InvoiceId | Price |
+--------+-----------+-------+
|  200   |   1000    | 10000 |
|  201   |   1001    | 22000 |
|  202   |   1002    | 30000 |
+--------+-----------+-------+

+--------+-----------+-------+
| PartId | PaymentId | Price |
+--------+-----------+-------+
|  200   |   1000    | 1000  |
|  200   |   1001    | 3000  |
|  201   |   1002    | 5000  |
+--------+-----------+-------+

+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| InvoiceId | PaymentId | Balance Need to be Paid |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
|  1000     |   1000    | 9000                    |
|  1000     |   1001    | 6000                    |
|  1001     |   1002    | 17000                   |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
```

Since cursor is performance wise not too good, Without using cursor is there any possible way to update the invoice payment mapping table?

Comment: What is the invoice mapping table?  How do you want to update it?  Your question is not clear.

Comment: the 3 rd table is the invoice payment mapping table.. What I wanna do is end of the day I have to map and see how much balance need to be paid for each and every invoice

Comment: Do you mean you have a cursor implementation and want to improve it? If so please give us the code.

Comment: Why do you even have the 3rd table? Couldn't you just use the 2 tables you have? If the purpose is to see something, just create a view.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single update.  The following is rather speculative, because your question is does not have all the necessary detail.  You can use `join` in the `update` query:

```
update ip
    set BalanceToBePaid = (i.price - p.sumprice)
from invoicepayment ip join
     invoices i
     on ip.invoiceid = i.invoiceid join
     (select paymentid, sum(price) as sumprice
      from payments
      group by paymentid
    ) p
    on ip.payment = p.payment;
```

Comment: Initially, I won't have any records in mapping table. End of the day I need to add records to mapping table, and see how much I need to collect for each and every invoice. Is that clear now?